# How to create a helper template for checking whether a value is equal to one of N other values

Tags: c++, templates

motivation: I would like to create a utility class so that instead of having to write:

```
if( someVal ==  val1 || someVal == val2 || someVal == val3 )
```

I could instead write:

```
if( is(someVal).in(val1, val2, val3) )
```

which is much closer to the mathematical 'a is an element of (b,c,d)' and also would save on a lot of typing when the variable name 'someVal' is long.

Here is the code I have so far (for 2 and 3 values):

```
template<class T>
class is {
private:
    T t_;
public:
    is(T t) : t_(t) { }

    bool in(const T& v1, const T& v2) { 
        return t_ == v1 || t_ == v2; 
    }
    bool in(const T& v1, const T& v2, const T& v3) { 
        return t_ == v1 || t_ == v2 || t_ == v3; 
    }
};
```

However it fails to compile if I write:

```
is(1).in(3,4,5);
```

instead I have to write

```
is<int>(1).in(3,4,5);
```

Which isn't too bad, but it would be better if somehow the compiler could figure out that the type is `int` with out me having to explicitly specify it.
Is there anyway to do this or I am stuck with specifying it explicitly?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you want to keep this syntax, you can use a helper function like :

```
template<class T>
class is_op {
private:
    T t_;
public:
    is_op(T t) : t_(t) { }

    bool in(const T& v1, const T& v2) { 
        return t_ == v1 || t_ == v2; 
    }
    bool in(const T& v1, const T& v2, const T& v3) { 
        return t_ == v1 || t_ == v2 || t_ == v3; 
    }
};


template< class U >
inline is_op<U> is( U const& v )
{
    return is_op<U>( v );
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    is( 1 ).in( 1 , 2 , 4 );
}
```

Comment: Typical way, write the class which provides the functionality and then write a function to create the instance of the class since functions support type deduction.

Answer (score 5):

The problem is quite amusing, it's true that boolean conditions can get hairy.

I myself tend to prefer writing special functions though, because the meaning here is hard to convey. What does:

```
if (someVal == val1 || someVal == val2 || someVal == val3)
```

means ?

Is

```
if ( is(someval).in(val1, val2, val3) )
// or
if ( is(someval).in(val1)(val2)(val3) ) // implements short-circuiting
                                        // and removes arity issue
                                        // using a proxy object
```

better?

I think it would be easier to read with:

```
bool isToBeLogged(const Foo& foo)
{
  // Either
  static std::set<Foo> ValuesToLog = /* some boost assign magic or whatever */;
  return ValuesToLog.find(foo) != ValuesToLog.end();

  // Or
  return foo == val1 || foo == val2 || foo == val3;
}


if (isToBeLogged(someVal))
```

I guess it's a matter of style.

The advantages of the second method including:

- In case the test is done more than once, the logic is not scattered all around (so changes are easy)
- No need to comment the test, the method name does it already

Inconvients ? I guess it's more typing... oh well :p

Comment: I wonder how you would implement short-circuiting? You won't pass the result of a function call, but an object that calls a function when looked up? - But generally, couldn't you combine the approaches (use is.in to implement isToBeLogged)?

Answer (score 1):

```
template<typename T>
is<T> is_value(T value)
{
    return is<T>(value);
}

int main()
{
    bool r ;

    r = is_value(1).in(3,4,5);
    r = is_value(3).in(3,4,5);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the general problem, a utility function like contains might be handy:

```
#include <boost/range.hpp>
template <class Range, class T>
bool contains(const Range& range, const T& value)
{
    return std::find(boost::begin(range), boost::end(range), value) != boost::end(range);
}
```

(Boost usage makes it also accept arrays, although one might write that overload separately. This could also be overloaded for containers with the find member function.)

In C++0x this could be extended to support `std::initializer_list<T>`* allowing rather nice usage:

```
if (contains({1, 2, 3}, value) {...}
```

---

* Not sure if it shouldn't work already, but my compiler requires an overload to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

You are stuck with it - the constructor requires the type to be provided as a template parameter. And I should observe that I really don't like your idea (especially the class name). Why not use  a std:;set? Or even a template function - something like:

```
template <typename  T>
bool IsIn( T v, T a, T b, T c ) {
   ...
}
```

Comment: Actually I started with something similar to IsIn because a class called 'in' seemed like asking for trouble, but in the end I decided I preferred is(a).in(b,c) for readability. Re using std::set -  my use case is I want to be able to do this in one line, not have to add members to the set and then check for membership. (BTW I didn't downvote you)

Comment: Regarding the class name: Put it in a namespace and it would be OK? (How likely is it that C++ would get an **is** keyword?! Isn't that what everybody calls their istreams?)

Answer (score 0):

a modification for your comparison class is perhaps to use varargs, to make it general to n elements of the set.

Comment: varargs don't work for most types of T? Variadic templates or `initializer_list` in C++0x would be another matter.